# Accessing a private S3 bucket via HTTP(s) from an embedded device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, arduino-esp32

My goal is to download a firmware image hosted in a non-public S3 bucket on AWS to my ESP32 board. I already have a quite big project running on it using an arduino framework via platformIO on VScode.

I found several tutorials, especially regarding [FreeRTOS AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/freertos/latest/userguide/freertos-ota-dev.html) stuff but following this approach I would have to start from scratch and since I am not interesting in a production suitable environment but rather for a simple straight forward approach I was thinking about simply downloading the file from S3. What is very easy using the python based boto3 library seems to be not so easy (or I am blind) using self build HTTPS requests.

I wanted to take [this example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Update/examples/AWS_S3_OTA_Update/AWS_S3_OTA_Update.ino) as a basis, but it I do not know how to authenticate or properly construct the HTTPS header. Using port 80 (HTTP) I only receive: `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`
Here is a part of the linked example I would use as a starting point:

```
WiFiClient client;
String host = "esp-data-exchange.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com";
int port = 80; // Non https. For HTTPS 443.
String bin = "/firmware.bin"; // bin file name with a slash in front.
client.connect(host.c_str(), port)
client.print(String("GET ") + bin + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                 "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                 "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n" +
                 "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

Using 443 I get a timeout trying to connect.

So if someone could point me into a direction on how to properly build the header and authenticate to access the file on S3 I would be very thankful. Using pre-signed URL is an option but those URLs expire and creating as well as providing my ESP32 with updated pre-signed URLs e.g. via MQTT AWS IoT broker is possible but not as straight forward as I would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign your HTTP/HTTPS request. If you cannot do it from the device side, you could create a new API using API Gateway (protected by API Keys) that integrates with S3 directly (Keep in mind the payload limit of API gateway: 10MB) to download your file. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) is a tutorial about this approach.

Comment: Thank you for the link - I will check it out over the weekend. However, I believe I can "sign" it from the device side, but I dont want to use pre-signed URL, instead I would prefer using AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY or whatever other *permanent* approach would work. Do you have an idea on how to sign the link using keys or certificates?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/create-signed-request.html#code-signing-examples

Comment: Thank you, in "Step 1: Create a canonical request", the last line includes the payload hash. Since I am requesting to download a binary file from S3, is my HTTP body simply empty and thus the hash is: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
?